# Hide all recommended videos and channel on homepage in YouTube

Tags: youtube

How to hide all recommended videos and channels on homepage in YouTube?
It used to be easy, I changed something in settings, and I closed new channel recommendations whenever they appeared, and my home page was nice and clean.

Apparently Google changed an algorithm, and closing recommendations doesn't help any more.

I've tried to find and apply filters I found in the internet, but it seems like they are outdated.

Comment: I don't want youtube as a TV. Don't want to watch every video which is picked up by their AI algorithm. I do not want to abuse youtube developers, but their algorithm for recommendations has an intellegence level of cockroach (it's very shallow tree of reasoning) and also has not enough data to predict what I really need. It is very good at distracting me and consume my time on unnecesary staff though... I understand that youtube is optimised with "attention economy" approach in mind. But I want to watch only search-driven content, it is more effective in my educational pursuits...

Answer (score 2):

I understand your frustration. I too deeply dislike Youtube's home page. It is very distracting for me.

My solution is to use ublock origin. It is an adblocker add-on that allows you to choose elements on any page to block from loading. If you use "zapper" mode, it will let you choose elements to block with the mouse cursor (the elements will be highlighted yellow).

I used zapper mode to turn off everything below the search bar. As a result, my youtube homepage now looks like this:

[image]

Very nice and clean! :)

The only problem I have is, this method causes youtube channels to go blank too. If you open a user's channel, then their page will be blank too. However, ublock origin can be turned on and off very easily. You can even turn it off only for a specific page, so if you find a channel you want to see, then use this option. The channel will load, but you will still be blocking the youtube home page elements.

I hope this helps you as it has helped me.